# Member Listserv Sync with CiviCRM

Tags: civimember, email

Wordpress 5 - Civi 5.10.0

We currently have a google group that we manually manage for active members - its beginning to become an unwieldy job to manage.

I understand there is a Google Groups one way solution - but I am more interested in seeing if there is an alternative solution out there that would automatically sync with members - or synced wordpress roles.

Also - we don't use buddypress - but open to any ideas you all may have related to BP.

Thanks!